# Reading input into dynamically-sized array

Tags: c++, python, io

What I've been trying to do, is read a line from stdin and split it, by using whitespace as seperators.

Let's say I have this as input:

> 2
>   1 2
>   3 4

The first line gives me the amount of lines I'd like to read, they're all lines with integers seperated by an unknown amount of whitespace (i.e. could be 1 space, but it could also be 10 spaces).
The thing I've been trying to do is reading those lines into dynamically sized arrays of integers.

This was extremely easy in Python:

```
foo = raw_input()
array = foo.split()
```

or even shorter:

```
foo = raw_input().split()
```

However, because of the circumstances, I have to learn the beauty of C++.
So I tried to create something akin to the above Python code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int lines;
int *array;

int main() {
    cin >> lines;
    for (int line = 0; line < lines; line++) {
        // Something.
    }
}
```

I don't seem to know a way to split the line of input. I know that std::cin reads until it reaches a whitespace. However, I can't seem to think of something to count the amount of numbers on the line...

A little nudge into the right direction would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: just a curiosity: why `import sys` ?

Comment: ... Ah, right. I meant to put in the sys.stdin version, but I guess I went for lazy and used raw_input(). Fixed.

Comment: Is this question about dynamically sized arrays, or about reading input? What I mean is, are you confused about how to split strings in C++ or how to put the values into an array, the length of which you are unsure of to begin with?

Comment: It's focus lies on input. I seem to be struggling with that. I've got the bit with the arrays down now, be it vectors or the built-in ones. The part I'm not getting is the splitting of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so given all you wanted is a nudge, here are a couple of hints..

[`std::getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/) - allows you to read from a stream into a `std::string`.

You can then construct a `std::istringstream` using this string which you've just read in. Then use this stream to read your ints

for example:

```
std::string line;
if(std::getline(std::cin, line))
{
  std::istringstream str(line);
  int lc;

  if (str >> lc) // now you have the line count..
  {
    // now use the same technique above
  }
}
```

oh and for your "dynamically sized array", you need to look at [`std::vector<>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/)

Comment: Somehow std::istringstream str(line) doesn't compile: "variable `std::istringstream str' has initializer but incomplete type". The std::getline() function does come in handy, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you can access characters in a string with [], just as if that string were an array. I suggest you read a line from cin into a string, iterate over the string with a for loop and check each character to see whether it is whitespace. Whenever you find a non-whitespace character, store it in your array.